# Grails Async: @Subscriber "SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed"

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have several Grails Services that are using the Grails Async Framework, but I'm running into problems with Hibernate closing the connection before the Subscriber method saves the domain object. However, if sleep the Subscriber thread briefly (100ms), I don't get the error.  Can someone please help me understand what's going on?

### Service

```
package com.my.company

import grails.events.annotation.Publisher
import grails.events.annotation.Subscriber
import grails.gorm.transactions.Transactional
import org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition
import us.cloudcard.api.exception.InvalidResourceException

class AdditionalPhotoService {

    S3Service s3Service
    AdditionalPhotoDataService additionalPhotoDataService
    PhotoService photoService
    PhotoDataService photoDataService
    FacialRecognitionService facialRecognitionService

    @Publisher(Event.ADDITIONAL_PHOTO_CREATED)
    @Transactional(rollbackFor = Throwable.class)
    AdditionalPhoto create(AdditionalPhoto additionalPhoto) {
        additionalPhoto.validate()
        if (additionalPhoto.hasErrors())
            throw new InvalidResourceException(additionalPhoto.errors)

        additionalPhoto.save()
        additionalPhoto.externalURL = s3Service.storePhoto(additionalPhoto)

        return additionalPhoto
    }

    byte[] fetchBytes(AdditionalPhoto additionalPhoto) {
        if (!additionalPhoto.bytes)
            additionalPhoto.bytes = RestUtil.getBytes(additionalPhoto.externalURL)

        return additionalPhoto.bytes
    }

    @Transactional
    @Subscriber(Event.ADDITIONAL_PHOTO_CREATED)
    void compareToPhoto(AdditionalPhoto additionalPhoto) {
        log.debug("comparing faces for additionalPhoto #$additionalPhoto.id")
        if (!additionalPhoto.additionalPhotoType.enableFacialRecognition) return

// this method only works if I uncomment this sleep call
//        sleep(100)

        photo = photo ?: additionalPhoto.person.currentPhoto
        additionalPhoto.facialRecognitionScore = facialRecognitionService.compareFaces(photoService.fetchBytes(photo), fetchBytes(additionalPhoto))
        additionalPhoto.save()
    }
```

### Exception

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: could not prepare statement; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [select person0_.id as id1_18_0_, person0_.version as version2_18_0_, person0_.date_created as date_cre3_18_0_, ... {extraneous query columns removed} ... from person person0_ where person0_.id=?]; SQL state [null]; error code [0]; PooledConnection has already been closed.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:89)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertJdbcAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:725)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.convertHibernateAccessException(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:712)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:301)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.get(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:364)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.autoRetrieveAssocations(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:325)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:146)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormInstanceApi.save(GormInstanceApi.groovy:119)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:100)
    at us.cloudcard.api.AdditionalPhoto.save(AdditionalPhoto.groovy)
    at us.cloudcard.api.AdditionalPhoto.save(AdditionalPhoto.groovy)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$save.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
    at us.cloudcard.api.AdditionalPhotoService.compareFaces(AdditionalPhotoService.groovy:109)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:351)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:64)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:176)
    at us.cloudcard.api.AdditionalPhotoService$__tt__compareToAdditionalPhoto_closure9.doCall(AdditionalPhotoService.groovy:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2330)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2315)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2368)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$188.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:244)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
    at us.cloudcard.api.AdditionalPhotoService.$tt__compareToAdditionalPhoto(AdditionalPhotoService.groovy:118)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePogoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:1011)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:994)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethodSafe(InvokerHelper.java:97)
    at us.cloudcard.api.AdditionalPhotoService$_compareToAdditionalPhoto_closure7.doCall(AdditionalPhotoService.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:94)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140)
    at grails.gorm.transactions.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:91)
    at us.cloudcard.api.AdditionalPhotoService.compareToAdditionalPhoto(AdditionalPhotoService.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282)
    at grails.events.subscriber.MethodSubscriber.call(MethodSubscriber.groovy:51)
    at org.grails.events.EventSubscriberTrigger.proceed(EventSubscriberTrigger.groovy:34)
    at org.grails.events.bus.ExecutorEventBus$_buildNotificationCallable_closure1$_closure3.doCall(ExecutorEventBus.groovy:36)
    at org.grails.events.bus.ExecutorEventBus$_buildNotificationCallable_closure1$_closure3.call(ExecutorEventBus.groovy)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.run(Closure.java:486)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: PooledConnection has already been closed.
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DisposableConnectionFacade.invoke(DisposableConnectionFacade.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy115.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor238.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy$LazyConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(LazyConnectionDataSourceProxy.java:385)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor238.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:241)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy124.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:198)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4415)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4405)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:569)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:537)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:332)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1184)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1173)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2765)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2721)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2765)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:981)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.lambda$get$0(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:364)
    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.GrailsHibernateTemplate.doExecute(GrailsHibernateTemplate.java:297)
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

### This works, but I don't want to have to sleep the thread

```
    @Transactional
    @Subscriber(Event.ADDITIONAL_PHOTO_CREATED)
    void compareToPhoto(AdditionalPhoto additionalPhoto) {
        log.debug("comparing faces for additionalPhoto #$additionalPhoto.id")
        if (!additionalPhoto.additionalPhotoType.enableFacialRecognition) return

        // this method only works if I use this sleep call
        sleep(100)

        photo = photo ?: additionalPhoto.person.currentPhoto
        additionalPhoto.facialRecognitionScore = facialRecognitionService.compareFaces(photoService.fetchBytes(photo), fetchBytes(additionalPhoto))
        additionalPhoto.save()
    }
```

Comment: I'm seeing something similar where it appears to be quite difficult to get an action fired off by an Event to attach to a Transaction. On that note, you don't need to explicitly specify `rollbackFor = Throwable.class`, because Spring will rollback the transaction if an Error occurs by default. Thus, both of your method annotations are effectively the same, so you can replace them with a single Service annotation instead.